# Calculating months with pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having trouble calculating the months properly. What I have so far is below as well as the output.
While most of the months calculate properly, some do not. I need to figure this out as it's bugging me.
Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'StartDate' : ['2017-06-19', '2017-10-01', '2017-09-29', '2017-08-01', '2017-08-01'],
    'EndDate'   : ['2018-06-18', '2017-12-31', '2018-09-30', '2018-07-31', '2017-09-30'],
    'ExpectedMonths'    : [13, 3, 13, 12, 2]
})

df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['calculatedMonths'] = (df["EndDate"] - df["StartDate"]) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
df['ceilMonths'] = df['calculatedMonths'].apply(np.ceil)
```

Output so far:
As you can see, the first row should be 13 but I am seeing 12 in the results. June to May should be 12 and add another month (June) that should be 13.

```
        EndDate     ExpectedMonths      StartDate   calculatedMonths    ceilMonths  
0       2018-06-18  13                  2017-06-19  11.959178           12.0
1       2017-12-31  3                   2017-10-01  2.989794            3.0
2       2018-09-30  13                  2017-09-29  12.024888           13.0
3       2018-07-31  12                  2017-08-01  11.959178           12.0
4       2017-09-30  2                   2017-08-01  1.971293            2.0
```

What do I need to adjust in order to get the expected output and the calculated months to match?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [117]: df["EndDate"].dt.to_period('M') - df["StartDate"].dt.to_period('M')
Out[117]:
0    12
1     2
2    12
3    11
4     1
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Going from the 19th of June to the 18th of June is going to get you just under 12 months which is why the ceiling is 12.

From June to June is 12 months not 13...  It's a full year.
Your expected months should be 12 for indices 0 and 3.

Here's some corrected code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'StartDate' : ['2017-06-19', '2017-10-01', '2017-09-29', '2017-08-01', '2017-08-01'],
    'EndDate'   : ['2018-06-18', '2017-12-31', '2018-09-30', '2018-07-31', '2017-09-30'],
    'ExpectedMonths'    : [12, 3, 12, 12, 2]
})

df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['calculatedMonths'] = (df["EndDate"] - df["StartDate"]) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
df['roundedMonths'] = round(df['calculatedMonths'])

print(df)
```